# Not able to pick photos and videos from Google photos app in nexus 5 marshmallow

Tags: android, android-gallery

I'm having problems picking up a photo and a video at the same time in nexus 5 with "google photos" app. In other applications it works fine, the issue is only with google photos. Please help me so that I can see the full gallery (not only pic or only video).

This is the onclick of my button:

```
@Click(R.id.ivGallery)
    void addMedia() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        intent.setType("video/mp4");
        startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

Comment: have you add runtime permission?

Comment: no @DheerubhaiBansal but after giving permission manually from device, its not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to pick all types of Files.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
 intent.setType("*/*");
 startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put **setType()** for Image and Videos combined.
like :

```
intent.setType("image/* video/*");
```

This **setType()** is for both type media you have to select from gallery.

Comment: your answer is correct but its not working with the GOOGLE PHOTOS app ...this app is taking only first type of MIME

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why its not working for you, but I faced similar issue when getting photos from google-photos if photos are not saved on the device.
what I did basically is checking if the path is null (meaning the image isnt on the device) and if so I just crate a new file and read to a buffer from a stream and saving that to the new file.. work for me

```
    public static String getImagePathForImageDownloadedFromGooglePhotos(Context context, Uri uri)
{
    ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = null;
    try {
        parcelFileDescriptor = context.getContentResolver()
                .openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (parcelFileDescriptor == null)
        return null;

    FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(fileDescriptor);
    try {
        //noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
        File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date()));
        String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        try {
            try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * 1024];
                int read;

                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    output.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }

                output.flush();
                return path;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@Click(R.id.ivGallery)
void addMedia() {
    // ACTION_PICK : is showing many option
    // ACTION_GET_CONTENT : only gallery
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

    // other setType calls aren't required. 
    intent.setType("*/*"); 

    startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: not able to fit in image view after select the pic but yes... that works